# How to install WSO2 and ActiveMQ

Tags: linux, wso2, activemq-classic, middleware, wso2-esb

I have a project at work that needs to work with JMS (ActiveMQ in two different machines with Failover Protocol sharing a FileSystem), and the WSO2 ESB.

I can't find anything useful in the documentation at their website. Once I have deployed the ESB files into the Home Directory,

- Do I need to unzip the carbon as well? Or just the ESB?
- What do I do if I want to have more than one WSO2 Application in the same machine?
- Should I deploy the Carbon Core as well or just the ESB one and the second one?
- Will they share the web administration console? Or must there be a port for each WSO2 Application that exists?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the WSO2 ESB binary distribution [from this link](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/).

Prerequisites - You required to install oracle JDK. ESB 4.9.0 supports for the JDK 1.7/1.8

Currently, all products come as standalone servers, with their own management interface. You just need to extract wso2 product and change their offset value.

You can change offset value in carbon.xml file available inside [ESB_HOME]\repository\conf folder

Ex- If we change the offset value to two

```
<Offset>2</Offset>
```

This will offset all ports such as management console, http and https transport each and every port offset by two.

Then you can start another WSO2 product in different offset value. So you don't need to worry about management console or carbon core.

You can follow [this link.](http://www.krishantha.net/start-multiple-wso2-esb-instances-on-same-computer/)